# Making a one-file visually customisable installer with patching/updating for XNA C# game

Tags: c#, xna, installation, updates

I'm making an XNA game and thought I'd look into making installers for it for when it's finished. It would be great to be able to distribute a single file that contains all the content and extracts all that to the install directory. Also I'd want to choose install directory and other options, and it would be nice to set the appearance of the installer to be in the style of my game.
Updates and patching are also something I'd want to set up. I have a website, so I'd like the game to check for updates from there.

I am familiar with ClickOnce, but I don't feel it is appropriate for the situation, and I've looked at Advanced Installer, Inno installer and wix.

I would love to make my own installer in c# winforms or similar, but I'm new to the area and don't know if this is possible or where to start. I trawled the net but could only find links to the third party stuff, so maybe makign my own is impossible? I wouldn't be bothered about not having start menu entries or registry values or whatever, just want to extract files somewhere then later check for updates before running.

Thanks for helping a newbie!

Comment: You could just customize Wix. It is in source format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WiX is a good option for all the requirements you have listed above.

> It would be great to be able to distribute a single file that contains all the content and extracts all that to the install directory

Standard WiX Setup project can get you going with this. There are default templates for basic installers

> Also I'd want to choose install directory and other options

The default templates are all customisable, so you would be able to collect additional data easily, what you do with the data is up to you.

> and it would be nice to set the appearance of the installer to be in the style of my game

WiX 3 onwards (I think) has a project type of 'Bootstrapper' which allows you to put your own UI infront of the installer, such as WPF or even XNA itself if you really wanted. You can specify and budle the requirements for the installer, eg .NET 4.0 if you are using a WPF front end.

> I would love to make my own installer in c# winforms or similar

Also an option with WiX Bootstrapper.

Installers are more complicated than you might think, also, for updates and patches, keeping information around of versions of files and how to handle them gets complex fast. My advice would be spend time on your **game** and take advantage of the hard work of [others](http://robmensching.com/blog/) who have thought long and hard about these problems.